# utf 8 compatibility in html 4 & html 5

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

I would ask about utf 8 compatibility,

utf-8 in Html 5 is a default charset encoding, and a ISO-8859-1 is a default for html4

now when I use an html5 ver, and user was used unsupported html5 browsers, what will be happened? its will execute utf-8, or ISO, or I must do something for process it?

also we know in html5 we used a

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and in html 4 we used a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default encoding defined in HTML 4. Instead, it defines [how the character encoding is determined](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#idx-character_encoding-7), and adds that in addition to this (in practice, when the author does not indicate the encoding that way), “the user agent may use heuristics and user settings. For example, many user agents use a heuristic to distinguish the various encodings used for Japanese text. Also, user agents typically have a user-definable, local default character encoding which they apply in the absence of other indicators.”

HTML5 basically just [spells this out](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) in more detail, describing what browsers actually do. Depending on browser locale, the default might be windows-1252 (which is what declaring iso-8859-1 actually means to browsers), or it might be something else.

There is no browser that conforms to HTML 4, and no browser that conforms to any flavor of HTML 5 (which is work in progress). Most modern browsers come reasonably close to supporting most of both of them.

The `meta` tags you mention work equally well in all browsers (excluding ancient versions you might find in a dark corner of a museum if you are lucky). Only the latter formally conforms to HTML 4, but this does not matter; the former, simplified version was taken into HTML5 as an alternative when it was observed that it works just fine (due to some parsing oddities). However, both of them can be trumped, by the specs and in practice, by an HTTP header.

Comment: thank you very much for very nice answer, Im read about it http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp, so I think Im not understand is exactly ^_^.. your answer was change my knowledge now ..

also, now If I understand it more clear, I can use html5 meta utf-8 charest, and its will compatible for most of browser exception very old browser ..thats true? 

thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

> a ISO-8859-1 is a default for html4

No, it isn't. The [default is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#idx-character_encoding-6):

> heuristics and user settings

---

> now when I use an html5 ver, and user was used unsupported html5 browsers, what will be happened?

The choice of Doctype (at least among standards mode triggering ones) has no impact on how the browser determines what character encoding to use.

---

> or I must do something for process it?

Specifying a character encoding explicitly is always a safe bet.

Comment: thank you mate ... ^_^, very nice answer, need some thinking ..thans a lot